# I do not know where my fault is

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class Circle {
    double radius;
    double pi=3.14;
}

public class CircleCalculation {
    double Sum(Circle r1,Circle r2) {
        double areaofCircle1=r1.radius*r1.radius*r1.pi;
        double areaofCircle2=r2.radius*r2.radius*r2.pi;
        return areaofCircle1+areaofCircle2;
    }
}

public class CircleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle r1=new Circle();
        Circle r2=new Circle();
        CircleCalculation c=new CircleCalculation();
        double sum=c.Sum(r1, r2);
        System.out.println(sum);
```

In Netbeans, I cannot run the program but it shows no faults.

Comment: Please put a meaningful title on your post.

Comment: I don't see anywhere you've set the `radius` variable

Comment: What steps did you try to run?

Comment: Define "cannot run." Do you mean it won't compile, it throws an Exception when you try to run it, or it runs but gives incorrect output?

Comment: For example when I write 1 and 2 instead of r1 and 2.
 double sum=c.Sum(1, 2);
        System.out.println(sum); and a mistake occurs and says incompatible types.  @resueman

Comment: If that's the code that won't compile, then you should put it into your question. The reason it won't work is because `1` and `2` are `int`s, not `Circle`s. Instead, you should use `r1.radius=1; r2.radius=2; double sum=c.Sum(r1, r2);`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure each class is in separate file. They have to be since they're public.

Besides, make sure all the classes are in the same package. Otherwise the `r1.radius` and `r2.radius` or `c.Sum(r1, r2)` calls won't work.

Of course, you also miss two `}` at the end of the snippet. Not sure if it's only matter of pasting.

However, in all cases you should get compilation error, so probably it's a matter of how you set up your project in Netbeans.